# Regular expression for Google analytics for matching the domain name in a URL

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am too new to regular expressions and my effort at it so far seems futile. I'm trying to write a very simple regexp to match a domain name like `google.com` with any URL referrer like `https://www.google.com`.

So far I have tried `/*google.com*/`, `(*google.com*)` and `[*google.com*]` and none of these have worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regular expression. I assume you are applying this on the `Hostname` dimension.

`.*google\.com.*`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question. I would like to match this to a URL referrer, not the URL. Either way, the regex you posted did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Where are you trying to apply the regular expression? Is it in one of the data tables, segment, or filters?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a regex which matches prefixes, such as e.g.: *https*, *http*, *ftp* & *sftp*.

The regex can be found here:

http://rubular.com/r/7sLhefh2xE